# Interesting mistake in string pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I created a function which transforms a number to its equivalent in given base and prints it into a string. It looks like flawless but gives absurd results. Code below should translate 100 to base 9 and give "121".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void doldur(string *s,int u,int base){
    *s="";
    while(u!=0){
        *s=""+u%base+*s;
        u/=base;
    }
    return;
}
int main() {
    ofstream fout ("dualpal.out");
    ifstream fin ("dualpal.in");
    int i;
    string hey;
    doldur(&hey,100,9);
    cout<<hey;
    cin>>i;
    return 0;
}
```

But ridiculously, it prints dualpal.outualpal.outdualpal.out.(Also gives other interesting results for different bases)

Where's the flaw?

Comment: `""` is not of type `std::string`.

Comment: Why are you declaring `fout` and `fin` if you never use them?

Comment: Specifically, it matters in this line: `*s=""+u%base+*s;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incrementing a pointer to an empty string by `u%base` places and then using it to construct a `std::string`, which looks for a null terminator. This causes undefined behaviour. Use a `std::string` off the bat:

```
*s = std::string() + ...;
```

Next, there's no conversion from `int` to `std::string`. Use a function like `std::to_string`:

```
*s = std::to_string(u%base) + *s;
```

The first operand was now pointless, so I removed it. Finally, all of that dereferencing is a bit tiresome, no? I'd make one and return it:

```
std::string doldur(const std::string &s,int u,int base){
    std:string ret;
    while(u!=0){
        ret = std::to_string(u%base) + ret;
        u/=base;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Don't worry about any performance loss from returning. Or use a reference and change the original if you prefer:

```
void doldur(std::string &s,int u,int) {
    s.clear();
    while(u!=0){
        s = std::to_string(u%base) + s;
        u/=base;
    }
}
```